# Issue with BrowserRouter - navigation doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is my first reactjs application and I have an issue with the navigation. When I try to navigate via url .../posts or ../home only the main App page is showing up. How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

I have App main page where user can Login or Register:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Register} from './subcomponents/Register';
import {Login} from './subcomponents/Login';

export function App() {
   return (
    <div className="root"> 
      <Login />
      <p>Hi {name}</p>
      <Register/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home page, when the user is logged in to be redirected:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Posts } from './Posts';
import {Home} from './Home.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Nav} from './Nav';

export function Home(){
    return(
        <div id="home">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Nav/>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>}/>
                    <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
            <h3>This is the home page</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Nav component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import '../css/nav.css';
import Logo from '../images/Logo.png';

export function Nav(){
    return(
        <div id="nav">
            <img src={Logo} className="nav-logo" alt="logo"/>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/posts">Posts</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `App` component isn't rendering any routes to match. Either render the `Home` component in `App` and remove the `"/"` route rendering `Home`, ***or*** move the routes into `App`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for access to components in the project by url,it need be to render before.

```
 export function App(){
        return(
             <BrowserRouter>
                <div id="app">  
                   <Routes>
                       <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>}/>
                       <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts/>}/>
                   </Routes>          
               </div>
           </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Not an accurate explanation. Route components can be used *anywhere* in the app. There's no requirement that they "***must*** be in app.jss/js". The issue is that the `App` component wasn't rendering any routes at all.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. I mean only for this project. I'm editing the explanation for misunderstanding at now.